# Adjust Kaplan-Meier Curve Given Cox PH Coefficient?

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

I have a survival dataset that I'm working with in R. I can generate a KM curve and also a table of survival and time values.

My question is, given a point on the survival curve (let's say 0.8 survival at 400 days), and a coefficient/hazard ratio from a cox model, how do I calculate how much to increase/decrease the survival value?

My goal is to be able to take the survival curve and adjust it up/down by an arbitrary hazard ratio/coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a continuous-time survival function $S(t)$ is related to the corresponding [cumulative hazard function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis#Hazard_function_and_cumulative_hazard_function) $\Lambda (t)$ by:

$$S(t) = \exp (-\Lambda (t)). $$

If you have a baseline survival curve $S_0(t)=\exp(-\Lambda_0(t))$ and want to estimate the corresponding survival curve for a particular hazard ratio $\text{HR}$ with respect to that baseline under proportional hazards, you first multiply the baseline cumulative hazard function by that hazard ratio. That gives you:

$$S(t|\text{HR}) = \exp(-\text{HR} \space \Lambda_0(t)) = S_0(t)^\text{HR}$$

So if baseline survival is 0.8 at 400 days and the hazard ratio is 2, the corresponding 400-day survival is $0.8^2=0.64$.

In practice, you are likely to get better results if you let well vetted software do these calculations for you. Note that the Kaplan-Meier survival curve for a baseline comparison group, for example an untreated control group, is *not* the same as that calculated from the baseline hazard estimated by your Cox model, which [pools information from all cases](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/206376/28500) and could have incorporated other outcome-associated covariates. You can ask the software to give you those refined estimates, along with confidence intervals, via functions having names like `survfit` or `predict`.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to experiment with rejection sampling to see how it compares with using other methods of simulating survival times, but I couldn't figure out how to adjust the survival curve.